# Uniswap swapExactTokensForTokens is making the transaction but not swapping between the coins

Tags: javascript, blockchain, swap

I'm trying to implement a basic swap between 2 coins, using ethers, but without success.

I get success:
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x9d09a50143f8e1ec1c72b17007d664b96e931a96cd1f08f5a78b94a9b834e691

but
the result is that I can see that the amount of the ETH is reduced, but my GCOIN and FLOG coin is still the same, what am I missing?

```
const walletAddress = "0xD5768aa815D590494277f558Ee5cbeC5FAF1501C";
const GCOINErc20Address = "0x0eb8c372066EbB30B256E8F8707EaA81cB68225D";
const FLOGErc20Address = "0x5a44be26dd414ebfc4beee5c40af5cc5272a62c7";
const ropstenUniswap = '0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D'
const uniswapRouterAbi = [
    "function swapExactTokensForTokens(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline) external returns (uint[] memory amounts)",
];

async function buyListedTokenWithEth(
    amountEthFloat,
    uniswapRouterAddress,
    provider
) {
    console.log('start')
    let privateKey = "private_key";
    let provider2 = ethers.providers.getDefaultProvider({name: 'ropsten', chainId: 3});
    console.log(provider2)
    let wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, provider2);
    const signer = wallet.connect(provider2); 
    const exchangeContract = new ethers.Contract(
        uniswapRouterAddress,
        uniswapRouterAbi,
        signer
    );
    const ethAmount = ethers.utils.parseUnits(amountEthFloat);
    console.log(exchangeContract)
    const tx = await exchangeContract.swapExactTokensForTokens(
        ethAmount,
        1,
        [FLOGErc20Address, GCOINErc20Address],
        uniswapRouterAddress,
        Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 10, //10 minutes,
        {
            'gasLimit': 300000,
            'gasPrice': ethers.utils.parseUnits('500', 'gwei'),
        });
    console.log("https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/" + tx.hash);
}

buyListedTokenWithEth('1', walletAddress, provider);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I see an issue here.

At a quick glance, it looks to me like you're sending the tokens to uniswapRouterAddress.  My understanding is that the 4th argument in swapExactTokensForTokens should be the address that you want to receive the swapped tokens.